# php artisan route:list error with gate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

So, I'm adding the Gate facade to my constructor in my UserController

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (Gate::denies('manage-user')) {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected but one thing, now `php artisan route:list` show following error

```
$ php artisan route:list

[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]
```

If I remove the Gate, `php artisan route:list` run fine. Anyone know why this is happening? And how to solve it? Can artisan bypass the Gate facade?

Comment: You're right, I just move the check from the constructor to my method, and php artisan route list works. So, if it wrong to put the check on the constructor, what is the best practice to put the gate check on whole controller (I just want to use 1 gate, manage-user, to all method on my user controller)? Do I have to put the check on all method manually? Would that break DRY principle?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, please write it as an answer so I can choose it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to avoid doing checks like this in a controller constructor. The Laravel docs show a number of ways to implement the authorization checks, none of them are in the controller constructor.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#checking-abilities

I would create a FormRequest personally, with an authorize method that does the check. Then you inject that FormRequest into each method, and it runs authorize automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#within-form-requests

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score -2):

I Used this command

```
public function __construct()
{
    // check if request not from cli
    if ('cli' != php_sapi_name()) {
        $this->authorize('is_admin');
    }
}
```